# How to get \hypereff[]{} working with htlatex?

Tags: hyperref, tex4ht, html, htlatex

In this minimal example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
Hahaha \hyperref[other]{2}
\end{document}
```

Compiling with pdflatex,  it ends up fine:

[image: pdf]

However when I compile it with

```
make4ht minimal.tex "mathml"
```

The html version does not show the number correctly.

[image]

I would like to know, how can I adjust htlatex so that it correctly produces documents with \hyperref?

Thanks

Comment: There's no anchor for that link: no `\label{other}` command anywhere. Once you add that, it works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like a bug in TeX4ht support for the `\hyperref` command. It uses the `\ref` command internally, so when the linked label is not found, it will print `??` to signalize the missing reference. As you don't have any `other` label in your document, you get this missing reference sign.

You can use the following config file to mimic the `\hyperref` behavior, which prints the text even when reference is missing:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\makeatletter
\def\label@hyperref[#1]{%
  \expandafter\label@@hyperref\csname r@#1\endcsname{#1}%
}%
\def\label@@hyperref#1#2#3{%
  \ifx#1\relax
    \protect\G@refundefinedtrue
    \@latex@warning{%
      Hyper reference `#2' on page \thepage \space undefined%
    }%
    \begingroup
      \hyperrefundefinedlink{#3}%
    \endgroup
  \else%
    \def\hyperrefLabel{#3}%
    \Configure{ref}%
      {\Link}{\EndLink}{\Configure{ref}{}{}{}#3}\ref{#2}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

compile using:

```
 make4ht -c config.cfg minimal.tex "mathml"
```

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!